# Learning VB.Net using Sharpdevelop

Tags: vb.net, sharpdevelop

I’m new to *visual basic.net*. I have experience in C++ programming, but never created gui with it so learning vb.net for some quick gui development. and i want to learn vb.net. *I can’t install visual basic express on computer cause i’m on shared computer* and such huge install is not possible on that computer. So i picked up sharpdevelop.

After searching most of the tutorial, i found out that most of tutorial written for visual studio IDE for vb and vb.net. I’m trying to learn vb.net in depth from command line to gui programs. Any good recommendation of tutorials, book ? I searched google but very few results so far. I’m looking for good learning tutorials that can help learn with sharpdevelop.

any suggestion for tutorial and books that mentions sharpdevelop in their tutorial/guide ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly - if you are thinking about heading into .net, you might want to consider starting off with c#, especially because with your background it will be a bit easier, but if you need to learn vb.net, ofc there is nothing wrong with it, just in my experience your earning potential is higher with c#, and vb.net is kind of dying out (at least in Europe).

Second point, you should focus on starting your development either for web or for win forms, this will give you a sense of direction. Learning a new language takes some dedication.

I also think you're putting yourself through unnecessary punishment by not using the tools provided by Microsoft for your development. In my experience Visual Studio, MS SQL and Microsoft Word, are the best products to ever come out of Microsoft. Even the express editions are of a good quality. If you can head over to an internet cafe and download it from there, shouldn't cause such a problem surely to have it installed on that computer, after all its going to be used for personal development, not just playing games or wasting time.

might not be the answer you wanted, but its the best advice I can give at this stage, hope it helps....!

Also this is said from personal experience, because I've been down that road, and I promise you I found developing with MS supplied IDE's much more enjoyable, and in the end, kept things viable.

Comment: +1, it helps one in another way. i tried to obtain vs from many places but failed so settled with sharpdevelop somehow :(

Answer (score 3):

I don't see how a "programming language" (like VB.NET) book is written for a specific IDE (like VS), even if the author mentions some instructions to do with VS (menus, settings, etc.), you should be able to follow along with him, because SharpDevelop simulates VS quite well.

I've never seen a .NET book which talks about doing things in SharpDevelop rather than VS, because VS is far more popular IDE, although some authors mentions the IDE as an alternate to VS.

There's a good book authored by SharpDevelop team which teaches C# techniques using their IDE, and its digital format is free, its name is [Dissecting a C# Application: Inside SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/InsideSharpDevelop.aspx), although there's no VB.NET version, AFAIK.

Another comment, I don't see why an experienced C++ programmer would learn VB.NET, if you want to learn a robust, quick GUI .NET language, go ahead and learn C#.

Good luck,,

Comment: actually i have few books where visual studio instructions are written and yes no sharpdevelop is in any book because of popularity of vs. is there any book or tutorial site you recommend for VB.NET?